# Symfony cannot post a ckeditor type

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor

The application working fine on **local**

But when deployed to **production**, got 403 error when doing a request with ckeditor content.

Normal text (e.g. `My content`) is working fine.

It's not working when the content is :

`<p> my content from ckeditor </p>`

and the response is 403 error (modifié)

Version used :

symfony 5, php 7.3.5 and cloud web ovh as hosting
My view :

```
        {{form_start(form)}}
            {{form_row(form.contenu)}}
            <div class="container text-center">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success button" value="Enregistrer">
            </div>
        {{form_end(form)}}
```

and my controller :

```
public function create(EntityManagerInterface $em, $part_id, $pack_id, $modul_id, Request $request)
{  
    $slide = new Slide;
    $form = $this->createForm(SlideType::class, $slide);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $params = $request->request->all();
        $slide->setContenu($params['contenu']);
        $em->persist($slide);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('show_part', array('pack_id' => $pack_id, 'modul_id' => $modul_id, 'id'=>$part_id ));
    }else{
        return $this->render('slide/new.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'PackController', 'pack'=>$pack, 'modul'=>$modul, 'part'=>$part, 'form'=>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your form builder code and also please explain why you want to use a own submit button instead of an submit button from the form builder?

Comment: @Atomzwieback using the own submit button (having NO submit button added to the form type itself) is actually *very* common to be able to reuse the form as a subform of another for example.

Comment: @Jakumi, i know but i would not do that if i use my form not within another form because it eliminates the risk of errors and as far as i see he isnt reusing his form in the actual code so may its better to use the form submit button.

Comment: the http status code 403 means "forbidden", which might mean that on success the `show_part` route denys the user access for some reason, or your user gets logged out in the meantime ... doesn't necessarily mean anything else really. But to check, you should have a look at the logs.

Comment: Yea may the user isnt authenticated or he hasnt the access rights to the route you want to redirect to. May he is able to provide some more code / informations like does doctrine stores everything right and what does the stack trace says

Comment: I just checked all your recommendations and I think the problem is that the user cannot publish texts containing css or javascript tags,
Can you tell me where and how can I change this?

Comment: Hi!
I checked the log several times but it does not display anything,
I even go into debug mode but the problem appears only in error 403 of the browser.
Can we order symfony to allow a request with text containing a css or javascript tag? If yes, how?